# How to add selft defined value to pivot?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm try to do a pivot to this dataframe,

```py
 column1  column2
 A        Y
 A        N
 B        Y
 B        N
 C        Y
```

count column2 by this code

```py
pivot=pd.pivot_table(dataframe,index=['column1'],columns=['column2'],values=['column1'], aggfunc={'column1':'count'}, margins=False, fill_value=0)
```

And the answer will be

```py
 count  Y   N
 A      1   1
 B      1   1
 C      1   0
```

, but if sometimes dataframe only contains one value 'Y',then the pivot will only have one column.

```py
 count  Y
 A      1
 B      1
 C      1
```

Is there any method to use two default value['Y','N'] to pivot column2, and always shows the result like this ?

```py
 count  Y   N
 A      1   0
 B      1   0
 C      1   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) column first - if missing `N` values is added with `0`:

```
dataframe['column2'] = pd.Categorical(dataframe['column2'], categories=['Y','N'])

pivot=pd.pivot_table(dataframe,
                     index='column1',
                     columns='column2',
                     values='column1', 
                     aggfunc={'column1':'count'}, 
                     fill_value=0)

print (pivot)
column2  Y  N
column1      
A        1  0
B        1  0
C        1  0
```

Or use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) after `pivot`:

```
pivot=pd.pivot_table(dataframe,
                     index='column1',
                     columns='column2',
                     values='column1', 
                     aggfunc={'column1':'count'}, 
                     fill_value=0)

pivot= pivot.reindex(['Y','N'], axis=1, fill_value=0)
print (pivot)
column2  Y  N
column1      
A        1  0
B        1  0
C        1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

If dataframe only contains one value either 'Y' or 'N', then other value can be addable by simple if condition after pivoting... Something like this ,maybe

```
if "N" not in pivot.columns:
    df["N"] = 0
if "Y" not in pivot.columns:
    df["Y"] = 0
```

Hope this Helps...